# "awk" not working when using it with "watch"

Tags: networking, ipv6, netstat, watch

In order to watch my IPv6 traffic totals I want to run this command:

```
netstat -s -6 | grep -i octet | grep -vi cast | awk '{ print $2/(1024*1024*1024) }'
```

combined with "watch -n1", so it gets run every second:

```
watch -n1 "netstat -s -6 | grep -i octet | grep -vi cast | awk '{ print $2/(1024*1024*1024) }'"
```

But it fails with:

```
awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /(1024*1024 ...
```

I've taken the one-liner from here: http://ipv6-or-no-ipv6.blogspot.de/2013/06/measure-ipv4-versus-ipv6-traffic-on.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a backslash before `$2`, that will fix the problem:

```
watch -n1 "netstat -s -6 | grep -i octet | grep -vi cast | awk '{ print \$2/(1024*1024*1024) }'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing the command in double-quotes `"`, you need to escape `"` and `$`

```
watch -n1 "netstat -s -6 | grep -i octet | grep -vi cast | awk '{ print \$2/(1024*1024*1024) }'"
```

If you are placing the command in single-quotes `'`, you do not have to escape `"` or `$`, however if you have single-quotes in the command, you have to end the single-quote and add an escaped single-quote `\'`

```
watch -n1 'netstat -s -6 | grep -i octet | grep -vi cast | awk '\''{ print $2/(1024*1024*1024) }'\'
```